# Node js cheerio showing wrong html source code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to scrape the url given in this code to get the coordinates using class `ng-binding` for tag `p`

```
Const request = require('request') 
Const cheerio = require('cheerio') 
Const logger = require('winston') 

request(`https://pokedex100.com/discord/coord=2zHeG5fz71icW`, function (error, response, html) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    logger.info(html);
                    var $ = cheerio.load(html)
                    var cord = $('p.ng-binding').text()
                    logger.error(cord)
                }
            });
```

I get the following html., which is not the same as what I get when viewing the source code manually. Can someone guide me on this?

```
22:32:43 - info: <!DOCTYPE html><html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Discord" />  <meta property="og:title" content="Discord - Free voice and text chat for gamers" />  <meta property="og:description" content="Step up your game with a modern voice & text chat app. Crystal clear voice, multiple server and channel support, mobile apps, and more. Get your free server now!"  /><meta property="og:image" content="https://discordapp.com/assets/ee7c382d9257652a88c8f7b7f22a994d.png" />  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@discordapp">  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@discordapp">
  <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lcbhdgefieegnkbopmgklhlpjjdgmbog">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/24cfd050a820092e88717a7b474a1087.css" integrity="sha256-WYgktx8T6Pkz7IBvCEpViHtcNBJDI9tykxV3SpLkz+s= sha512-fXegHnQBxgOX43MAMz9XZZpa4gxVLtgwj2vfRn/OOsMUGT+VJYqti68o0ok7QunHggCNlv1oNsM1DDl9o+jZJw=="><link rel="icon" href="/assets/07dca80a102d4149e9736d4b162cff6f.ico" />  <title>Discord</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app-mount"></div>
  <script>window.__require = window.require</script>
  <script>window.__OVERLAY__ = /overlay/.test(location.pathname)</script><script>!function(){if(null!=window.WebSocket){var n=function(n){try{var e=localStorage.getItem(n);return null==e?null:JSON.parse(e)}catch(n){return null}},e=n("token"),o=n("gatewayURL");if(e&&o){var r=null!=window.__require?"etf":"json",t=o+"/?encoding="+r+"&v=6";void 0!==window.Uint8Array&&(t+="&compress=zlib-stream"),console.log("[FAST CONNECT] "+t+", encoding: "+r+", version: 6");var a=new WebSocket(t);a.binaryType="arraybuffer";var s=Date.now(),i={open:!1,gateway:t,messages:[]};a.onopen=function(){console.log("[FAST CONNECT] connected in "+(Date.now()-s)+"ms"),i.open=!0},a.onclose=a.onerror=function(){window._ws=null},a.onmessage=function(n){i.messages.push(n)},window._ws={ws:a,state:i}}}}();</script><script src="/assets/ef85b442dc6e960fcdb2.js" integrity="sha256-YRcm2EGe1y248RLha42j5bJzgo7unYVPfEaRjIfI6OU= sha512-5rFJb426vcPzMhaOWbyhgHe5rP59EMHbQlYChDbJ5Ivjxkg3HBcF4qhU6d6OMxNaQ8ivLJGiReIVUNyQYKOE9A=="></script><script src="/assets/f36f220d9b6f06eed734.js" integrity="sha256-gERbeDHAE3txb+KP87BEkbIawMeMaMnLTZ5gGRXpYv8= sha512-2mJlwmLdySqA+3psIzKCkNG+ThSLeOAls13fO6sFLQveqomiys1HAei4MHx4eCYizZ1uzXqJWq6gmrmMpzHH+Q=="></script></body>

</html>
22:32:43 - error:
```

**Edit:**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, timeout: 1000000 });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000000)
    await page.goto('https://pokedex100.com/?d=dcgrtr4WmaRvW', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    await page.waitForSelector('input[id="register-email"]', { timeout: 1000000 });
    await page.type('input[id="register-email"]', "my_email_id")
    await page.type('input[id="register-password"]', "my_login_password")
    await page.click('button[class="btn btn-primary"]')
    await page.waitForSelector('button[class="primary"]', { timeout: 1000000 })
    await page.click('button[class="primary"]')

    page = await browser.newPage(); // See justification below
    page.waitFor(5000)
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000000)
    await page.goto('https://pokedex100.com/?d=dcgrtr4WmaRvW', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" })
    await page.waitForSelector('p[class="ng-binding"]', { timeout: 1000000 }).then(async cords => {
        //let cord = await page.$('p[class="ng-binding"]')
        console.log("target")
        console.log(page.target)
        page.$eval('p[class="ng-binding"]', element => {
            console.log("element.innerHTML")
            console.log(element.innerHTML)
            console.log(element.textContent)
            console.log(element.nodeName + ' ' + element.nodeValue)
        })
    })
```

The reason why I used, page = browser.newPage() is because, I observed that, it takes time for the page to load on the `target`, but it loads faster when i open the new window.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content of the page is loaded by a script on the page. `request` is just fetching the html, so it won't execute any scripts. You could use a headless browser (such as [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)) to load the page and allow the content to be populated before scraping.

Comment: If you can pls, post only an example how I can achieve this using puppeteer?

Comment: @Aka Actually my answer is wrong. The page being loaded is the discord login page because the page you're trying to scrape is protected by some kind of discord authentication. You may have to find a way to send a discord auth token with your request. The discord [oauth2 docs](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) might be helpful.

Comment: I read the docs, but i couldn't understand how i can pass this authorization....Will you look into this please That'll solve me a great amount of deal and frustration?

Comment: I tried using puppeteer, i created sort of a script that would click the authorize button and move to the actual cord page. But I need some pro to look at it and suggest me changes so that i can make it work fast or better....I'll edit my post with the new code